# Jcomponent content pane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, japplet, jcomponent

My question is , if the top level containers like frames,dialog and applet has a content pane with boarder layout as default which are inherited from JComponent **as the oracle doc says** then what is the relation between frames,app,dialog and jcomponent as all are top level containers?

Comment: Oracle doc says


Defaultcontentpane is a container that inherits from jcomponent and uses border layout as it's layout manager

Answer (score 2):

A `JComponent` is ***not*** a top level container.  I consider the definition of a top level container to be:

> A top level container can be displayed on its own, without the programmer explicitly adding it to any other container.

That is true of:

- `JFrame`
- `JApplet`
- `JWindow`
- `JDialog`

As advised by @camickr, see the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for more information.

[image]

..and note that while the `JFrame` is clearly marked as "A Top-level Container", the content pane (a `JComponent`) is *lacking that title.*

Comment: +1, see the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for more information.

Comment: Oracle doc says


Defaultcontentpane is a container that inherits from jcomponent and uses border layout as it's layout manager

Comment: O..K  Was that (supposed to be) a question?  Or are you just telling me something I already knew?

Comment: How can frame content pane inherit from jcomponent what is the relation between two?